# GeoServer using read only database

Tags: geoserver, oracle-dbms, indexing

Can GeoServer use an Oracle database that is in a read-only state or does it need the ability to generate its own indexes if existing databases do not have the necessary indexes already generated?

Comment: Yer mate, all good for read only.

Answer (score 3):

That will be fine, if the indexes are missing it will just be even slower than Oracle usually is.